# How can I remove a reference from an entity object to another entity with the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity `Locations` with its primary key consisting of `Longitude` and `Latitude` as `double`.

From another entity object I want to remove the reference to an entity object in `Locations` but every time I try to set the reference to null I get an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`.

```
using (MyModelContainer context = new MyModelContainer())
{
    Note note = context.Notes.Single(n => n.NID == NoteUpdate.NID);
    note.LocationReference.Load();
    note.LocationReference = null;
    context.saveChanges();
}
```

But it is not working. The same is with `note.LocationReference.Value = null`.

How can I set the reference to null or its default value?

Comment: Can you show your model for Note and Location?

Comment: The `Location` and `Note` are in a 0..1 to many relation. The `Location` has as primary keys `Longitude` and `Latitude` as `double`. `Note` has a Title, a Content and a ID.

Comment: Have you got any cascading deletes/updates set up?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the purpose is to update db so that location column of note row is set to null here, so detaching is not going to work. I think replacing `note.LocationReference = null;` with `note.Location = null;` in the code above should work

Comment: No, sorry, but that was the first thing i've tried. In that case you're deleting the Location and not the Reference to it.  And you're right, i want to update the db.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the reference? I believe that this will delete the parent row, but would be curious to find out if it only deletes the reference if you pass in the object tied to the note.

```
context.DeleteObject(note.LocationReference);
```

Typically, the optimistic concurrency error means that the value has changed since you last loaded the object, but it sounds like that is not the problem. But, to verify, nobody could be modifying this in between running the code, right?

Last, have you tried to set the State?

```
context.Entry(note).State = EntityState.Added
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Note class, add:

```
public int? LocationReferenceId {get; set;}
```

To remove the reference do:

```
Note.LocationReferenceId = null;
```

And then save the Note Object back to the db

I recon that should do the trick.